# How to open new ViewController of the Cell row and pass data programmatically without Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I want to open a DetailViewController by clicking of a row in the UITableView, pass data to show it in the DetailViewController and be able to return by back arrow. I know how to do it with the Storyboard and NavigationLink, but in this case I no have idea. How to do it programmatically without the Storyboard?
Here im my code:

ListViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController {

var collection: UICollectionView!
var tableView = UITableView()
private let viewModel = ListViewModel()
let detailViewController = DetailViewController() //I want to open this one

var users = [DataModel]()

struct Cells {
    static let listCellTablewViewCell = "ListCellTableViewCell"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    self.viewModel.bindPageViewModelToController = {
        self.fetchData()
    }
    setupUI()
    configureTableView()
}

func fetchData() {
    users += self.viewModel.pageData.data
    tableView.reloadData()
}

fileprivate func setupUI() {
    collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collection.backgroundColor = .red
    collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(collection)
    
    collection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    collection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
}

func configureTableView() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setTableViewDelegates()
    tableView.rowHeight = 100
    tableView.register(ListCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListCellTableViewCell")
    tableView.pin(to: view)
}

func setTableViewDelegates() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

}

extension ListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.listCellTablewViewCell) as! ListCellTableViewCell
    let data = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.set(data: data)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
   
}
}
}
```

ListCellTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class ListCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var firstNameLabel = UILabel()
var lastNameLabel = UILabel()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    addSubview(firstNameLabel)
    addSubview(lastNameLabel)
    
    configureFirstNameLabel()
    configureFirstNameLabel()
    setFirstnameLabel()
    setLastNameLabel()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func set(data: DataModel) {
    firstNameLabel.text = data.firstName
    lastNameLabel.text = data.lastName
}

func configureFirstNameLabel() {
    firstNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    firstNameLabel.backgroundColor = .red
}

func configureLastNameLabel() {
    lastNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    lastNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lastNameLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
}

func setFirstnameLabel() {
    firstNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    firstNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    firstNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

}

func setLastNameLabel() {
    lastNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lastNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lastNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    lastNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    lastNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller or do you want to show the detail modally?

Comment: There is no Storyboard. I don't know how to open new View when there is no Storyboard or SwiftUI. I want to click a row and then open a View which show a data of the Cell. I hope I wrote it understandably.

Comment: You can create a view controller instance by using an initialiser - `let newVC = DetailViewController()` and the set a property to pass the selected item, but do you have a navigation controller on your current view controller that you want to use or do you want to show the new view controlller modally?

Comment: Modally is good idea.

Comment: I did as you mentioned and it works. Thank you!